# Why are my videos rendering in black and white?

Tags: rendering, video

I am making an animation and when I render the animation, it turns out black and white.
I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Is the output set to BW in *render settings > output*? Do you have any composite nodes?

Comment: I do not have any composite nodes @gandalf3  I will see about the render settings.  Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Yes it seems that it is set to BW @gandalf3

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like the output might be set to BW in *Render settings > Output*. Make sure it is set to RGB instead (or RGBA if you need the alpha channel):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It worked!  I wasn't expecting such a quick response.  Thanks